# grpc-gateway: return 201 on successful POST

Tags: rest, grpc, http-status-codes, grpc-gateway

What's the idiomatic way to return an HTTP 201 on a successful POST with grpc-gateway?

[Writing a filter function](https://grpc-ecosystem.github.io/grpc-gateway/docs/customizingyourgateway.html#mutate-response-messages-or-set-response-headers) seemed promising, but I'm not sure how to do this generically since I don't have access to the request (and can't determine the HTTP verb used)

[Replacing a response forwarder](https://grpc-ecosystem.github.io/grpc-gateway/docs/customizingyourgateway.html#replace-a-response-forwarder-per-method) seems to have all the needed information, but it requires wiring up on every applicable request, which can be error-prone.

I know there's [not an equivalent gRPC status to HTTP 201](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/master/codes/codes.go) that can be mapped, so this would have to live entirely in the grpc-gateway code.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: No, I've changed jobs and technologies since this question was asked.